# How do I keep my laptop from hibernating when it is booting Ubuntu with the lid closed?

Tags: 15.04, hibernate

I have a laptop running Ubuntu.  I have made it so it reboots at 12 every day, but when it reboots it goes to hibernate.

Comment: What setup did you use to make it reboot at 12?

Comment: Do you say that it hibernates **instead** of rebooting? Or does it hibernate immediately **after** rebooting?

Answer (score 2):

Open the Dash and type Energy. Select the Energy icon. There's an option on that window to configure what happens when the lid is closed.